# How to append item to a list in another file and save that file with updated list

Tags: python, list

I have a python file (list.py) that has list as follows:

```
letters=['A','B','C']
```

I would like to be able to open and add next letter 'D' to letters and then save the updated list.py so that it will have the following list:

```
letters=['A','B','C','D']
```

that I will access and update in the future.

I tried to import list and use f.write but it saves output as string.

Comment: Why do you want to have Python files modify other Python files? There are other ways to store Python lists (for example, the pickle module).

Comment: I think what you want is [Pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html).

Comment: I would prefer to store in Python if there is a way to do it. Can you elaborate a bit more about use of Pickle.

Comment: I posted an answer but you should seriously consider the idea to use pickle, except if you want to modify ``.py`` files.

Comment: @user3151858 I've elaborated it in my answer

Answer (score 3):

For the functionality you want, you can use [pickle module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format). It's as simple as reading and writing into files.
Here is a simple example code for your particular case-
In this python script, A list `Letters` is created and saved to a file `"list.pkl"`-

```
import pickle

letters=['A','B','C']
#Writing the letters list into the file.
fh = open("list.pkl", 'wb')
pickle.dump(letters, fh)
fh.close()
```

Now, in the code below(executed in the shell), the `"list.pkl"` file is being read, and 'D' is appended to the list and the list is written back to the file-

```
>>> import pickle
>>> fh = open("list.pkl", 'rb')
>>> letters = pickle.load(fh)
>>> print letters
['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> fh.close()
>>> letters.append('D')
>>> fh = open("list.pkl", 'wb')
>>> pickle.dump(letters, fh)
>>> fh.close()
```

To check if the file actually has the value, restart the shell, and read the file again and display the list as demonstrated here -

```
>>> import pickle
>>> fh = open("list.pkl", 'rb')
>>> letters = pickle.load(fh)
>>> letters
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

This does what you want:

```
import re

text = '''
def f(i):
    return i*2

letters=['A','B','C']  

x = 1
print f(x)'''

# creating a file containing the list
with open('li.py','w') as f:
    f.write(text)

# reading the file
with open('li.py','r') as f:
    cont = f.read()

print cont

print '======================='

rgx = re.compile('(^letters *= *\[.*)(\][ \t]*$)',re.MULTILINE)

x = 'D'
print rgx.sub('\\1,%r\\2' % x,cont)
```

result

```
def f(i):
    return i*2

letters=['A','B','C']  

x = 1
print f(x)
=======================

def f(i):
    return i*2

letters=['A','B','C','D']  

x = 1
print f(x)
```

But there may be some particular cases, that I don't perceive for the moment, that could cause problems.

.

The regex pattern is composed of :

`\[.*\]` in which `\[` represents the character `[` (it is needed to escape it because `[` and `]`  in a regex pattern have special meanings)
and `\]` represents the character `]`

`.*` says represents a succession of any characters different from `\n`

`[ \t\r]*` represents a succession of blanks or tabs or the character `\r` (this one is preceding the newline `\n` in Windows OS).

`^` represent the start of a line and `$` the end of a line (before the `\n`) because the flag `re.MULTILINE` is activated.

At first the regex motor finds the string matching `^letters *= *\[.*` that is to say it finds the line beginning with `letters = [` and matches all the subsequent characters following the `[` until the end of the line, that is to say until the next `\n` (in fact `$` isn't really necessary because the dot doesn't match `\n`)

But then, since the next character must be `]`, the regex motor goes backward until finding this character. So the `]` that it finds is certainly the last one in the line. So there can be elements like `"[fgsrhsr]"` in the list without the regex motor considering this `]` in this element to be the `]` that must match with `\]`

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. However, I hoped there is more elegant way of doing without using re. It seems to me it's easier to use database in that case to store the data. I am also confused what def f(i) does.

Comment: I wanted to stay within list without going back and forth from string to list.

Comment: ``def f(i)``, ``x=1``, ``print f(x)`` are just there to make an environment for the line of interest ``letters = ....``, just to mimic a code file.